# Canon 18-55mm lens giving err01 after it fell down

Tags: canon, repair, lens-design, diy, error

Sometime back I accidentally dropped my canon EFS 18-55mm lens (open caps); I cleaned the contact areas and any kind of dirt I could see on it. After that it was a bit jittery whenever I zoomed, but soon it became normal as before. After taking a number of shots through it, it has started to show Err01 at following times :

- On taking flash-on shots at 18 mm
- On taking shot at auto-focus using remote live view function of canon app.
  ( *I have already tried cleaning lens and camera contacts.* *Lens is auto-focusing fine and clicking shots at other positions under flash-on*)

Also, I started to feel little tight while focusing down to 18mm focal length. Upon closer inspection, I found something loosely hanging inside the lens. Upon rotating the lens upside-down, it is moving inside and out:
[image: Seeing inside from lens front]

[image: Seeing inside from lens back]

[image: Image taken with black obstruction visible at top]

1. Seeing inside from lens front

2. Seeing inside from lens back

3. Image taken with black obstruction visible at top

Please share how terribly bad this problem is and whether lens could be repaired without loosing big amount of money?

Answer (score 11):

> whether lens could be repaired without loosing big amount of money?

*Whatever* the damage, repairing the 18-55 almost certainly isn't worth it. People upgrading sell them for not very much, just get a new one.

Answer (score 10):

The black obstruction looks like a detached aperture blade. This is a seriously damaged lens. Repairing it would at least require it to be dismantled and the aperture blades replaced. Possibly there is even more damage.

As the lens seems to be on the cheaper side, it seems to be more economic to replace it - maybe with a used one from one on the various second hand market places.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely an aperture blade.